# Is it possible to add KDE/dolphin service menu for specific file extension?

Tags: linux, kde, dolphin, servicemenu

In windows, you can and context menu entries that are only shown for specific file types only.

In Dolphin, I know how to add service menu entry using .desktop file. but Is there way to only show those service menus for specific file type?

Comment: odd that it wasn't answered yet. when this happens again try other stackexchage sites like askubuntu and superuser

Answer (score 4):

Under the section `[Desktop Entry]` should be the line that specifies the type of file for which that appears: `MimeType=`.

To limit that to mp4 files, it should be `MimeType=video/mp4`. To restrict to all videos: `MimeType=video/*`; to videos AND folders:`MimeTypevideo=video/*;inode/directory;`.

Also under the section `[Desktop Entry]` you need to have `Type=Service` (**NOT** `Application`) and the line `Actions=`, where you have to specify the name or names of the action or actions of the service menu, each action being a separate section of this file with a separate `name`, of the form `[Desktop Action name]`.

The `Exec=` line is to be set under each `[Desktop Action name]` section (**NOT** under `[Desktop Entry]`).

Here is an example with multiple actions.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Service
Name=Download subtitles (filebot)
ServiceTypes=KonqPopupMenu/Plugin
Actions=en;fr;ro;it;
MimeType=video/*;inode/directory;
Icon=gnome-subtitles
Encoding=UTF-8
X-KDE-Priority=TopLevel
X-KDE-Submenu=Subtitles

[Desktop Action en]
Exec=filebot -get-subtitles -rename -non-strict %f
Icon=gnome-subtitles
Name=English (filebot)
Termial=true

[Desktop Action fr]
Exec=terminator -e "filebot -get-subtitles --lang fr -rename -non-strict %f" -p ttt
Icon=gnome-subtitles
Name=Français (filebot)

[Desktop Action ro]
Exec=terminator -e "filebot -get-subtitles --lang ro -rename -non-strict %f" -p ttt
Icon=gnome-subtitles
Name=Româneşte (filebot)

[Desktop Action it]
Exec=terminator -e "filebot -get-subtitles --lang it -rename -non-strict %f" -p ttt
Icon=gnome-subtitles
Name=Italiano (filebot)
```

which will give this for videos and directories:

[image]

You may have one or multiple actions.

Other settings under `[Desktop Entry]`:

`X-KDE-Priority=TopLevel` will show the action (or its group: see below) directly in the menu, like in the image above; without that, it will be under 'Actions' group.

`X-KDE-Submenu=something` will group under one menu-group called 'something' all the actions from files that have that line in them. (Even if the actions are in different service menu files, as discussed in [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/343211/32012) question; also see [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/344053/32012) question.)