# Add another sub-level to KDE-Submenu in Dolphin actions/services?

Tags: .desktop, kde5, dolphin, servicemenu

Is it possible to create lower levels of sub-menus in Dolphin context menu than the one created by the line `X-KDE-Submenu=` under `[Desktop Entry]`?

---

Example:

I have created an action called "Subtitles" (`X-KDE-Submenu=Subtitles`) which contains 4 options for downloading different languages with the `filebot` tool. I know I can make that appear in the top level or under Actions. I have set it for toplevel with the line `X-KDE-Priority=TopLevel`.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Service
Name=Download subtitles (filebot)
ServiceTypes=KonqPopupMenu/Plugin
Actions=en;fr;ro;it;
MimeType=video/*
Icon=gnome-subtitles
Encoding=UTF-8
X-KDE-Priority=TopLevel
X-KDE-Submenu=Subtitles

[Desktop Action en]
Exec=filebot -get-subtitles -rename -non-strict %f
Icon=gnome-subtitles
Name=English (filebot)
Termial=true

[Desktop Action fr]
Exec=terminator -e "filebot -get-subtitles --lang fr -rename -non-strict %f" -p ttt
Icon=gnome-subtitles
Name=Français (filebot)

[Desktop Action ro]
Exec=terminator -e "filebot -get-subtitles --lang ro -rename -non-strict %f" -p ttt
Icon=gnome-subtitles
Name=Româneşte (filebot)

[Desktop Action it]
Exec=terminator -e "filebot -get-subtitles --lang it -rename -non-strict %f" -p ttt
Icon=gnome-subtitles
Name=Italiano (filebot)
```

[image]

After that I have created a second such file which is almost identical, only it uses the `subliminal tool`. Also, the two files have different names in `Name=` under `[Desktop Entry]`: one is `Name=Download subtitles (filebot)`, the other `Name=Download subtitles (subliminal)`.

Nevertheless, all the eight actions of these two files appear grouped together under 'Subtitles'.

[image]

I was expecting that the names in `Name=Download subtitles (filebot)` and `Name=Download subtitles (subliminal)` to count for something, but they seem to do nothing.

I have created two desktop files with 4 actions each but it looks as if I had created a single desktop file with 8 actions, because the two files have in common the line `X-KDE-Submenu=Subtitles`.

I know I can separate the actions of the two files by setting different `X-KDE-Submenu` names, but then I will have two different toplevel entries (or two separate entries in Actions if I remove  `X-KDE-Priority=TopLevel`).

But what I want is to have one toplevel entry called Subtitles with two sub-menus, one for filebot, the other for subliminal, and in each of these the four language options - similar to what I can add in a different OS in Nautilus. There, I have made this setting in Nautilus config tool:

[image]

Which gives this:

[image]

### Is something similar possible in Dolphin?

Comment: It's doable in KDE/Dolphin, but it requires C++ Programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After investigating a bit more I dare say the answer is probably **NO**.

The Nautilus sub-menus created through settings  in **nautilus action configuration tool** are  based on `.desktop` files created in `/.local/share/file-manager/actions`. But while the lowest levels (the actions themselves) are normal  desktop actions, the intermediary sub-menus (that can go on numerous levels and can be multiplied many times through the **nautilus action configuration tool**) are not such normal desktop files, but **contain Gconf settings**.

A Nautilus normal action is a desktop file that contains the line `Type=Action`; the multipliable menus are desktop files that contain the line `Type=Menu`, but also a line like `ItemsList=495e5ac1-e34b-4570-b7e2-fb2188410dff;034e7ec6-32f8-4538-956b-624e421593ac;c2ee726a-bda0-4e36-96db-e8cfaa7c83d6;f519ea3d-6937-457e-baf9-4a9dcd586062;`, which is the Gconf setting.

I guess that is not doable in KDE and Dolphin.